# Displaying images with no Save As

Tags: html, image

Just wondering how a lot of websites lately seem to be displaying images with no Save As function. I'm not sure if this is JavaScript/CSS displaying the images, examples of what I mean are such as in the header of stackoverflow or http://plarium.com/en/games/soldiers-inc/ in the column headers of player rankings, which change when clicked.

Appreciate any feedback

Comment: they are set as background images to div/a/i elements ..

Comment: There's loads of ways to do this. Background images, php generating scripts, js "no right click allowed" but I'd urge you not to do this if you wish to stop image theft purely because they will get stolen regardless and you might as well invest your time elsewhere (like htaccess hot link detection etc).

Comment: Thanks for replies. It wasn't to stop image theft just purely curiosity on how it was done, found Webinan's way of putting a blank DIV over the image does the job, kinda obvious now its been said haha...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with css `background-image`.
or put a blank and transparent DIV over your main image container.

Also browser inspectors are your friend in such cases, for example you can see that in stackoverflow's case, it's background-image as I said, see this http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=f936a8b3d6ea

Comment: Appreciate your reply. Found setting a DIV background-image in CSS still allowed me to save the background image (unless I'm missing something?) but putting a blank DIV over fixed that.

Comment: No problem, well try setting the css to an anchor tag instead of DIV `<a style="display:block; background:url(...); height:...; width:..."></a>`